# using of integer vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector, breadth-first-search

We initialize vectors in c++ like this..

```
vector<int> poz[10];
```

But what does this mean?(If k and j are integer variables)

```
d[poz[k][j]];
```

like in breadth first search.(e.g.)

Tell me if you want the code.

Comment: I have no particular desire for the code, no.

Comment: We initialize a vector with 10 elements like this `vector<int> poz(10);`, this `vector<int> poz[10];` is an array of ten vectors.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: There's no question.  The question is open for questions.

Comment: No downvotes yet. It's that Friday feeling.

Comment: Do **you** have *any* inkling what it may mean? *Any at all*? Even a wag (wild-ass-guess) ? Please, *please* [**read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [**read this**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not initialize a vector the way you suggest. What the code `vector<int> poz[10];` does is to declare an array of size 10 of vector of integers. So you have 10 vectors. You can access the first one using `poz[0]`(and its first element is `poz[0][0]`). In general `poz[i][j]` is the j-th element of the i-th vector.

Comment: Then poz[2].push_back(5) would mean to push 5 in 2nd vector ?

Comment: @user3845936 in fact in the third vector. Keep in mind arrays are 0-based in c++.